# PostgreSQL String Comparison

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, string-comparison

I would like to do a query to get all items with a string 'id' > a specified id.

The query `select * from machine_thread where id > 'znRb1c_3TPytk-JoPX19Qw'` returns an item with the id `zT4GabH3Qy2W6YIGh8Ku-w`

In the other languages i am using (python, javascript) a string comparison will show that 
`'znRb1c_3TPytk-JoPX19Qw'`  is greater than `'zT4GabH3Qy2W6YIGh8Ku-w'`. What is postgresql doing differently, and is there anyway I can use the same comparison across all environments for comparing string IDs?

Comment: Check your database configuration and the collation setting. I don't get the result you do in my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of `COLLATE` the PostgreSQL is using.

Execute `SHOW LC_COLLATE` to see, what collation you are using.

The collation you want (the one python and javascript are using) is `"C"`.

Example [`here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/554)

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)

Comment: Note that on Pg 9.2 you can set collations per-column and per-operation, so you don't have to mess up sorting of names to get C collation for this particular column.